# Getting a Chromium WebView on Android 4.4?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webview

I'm wrapping a web application in a mobile app by using a WebView. My application uses an audio framework, and webGL that both only run in the chrome browser. The problem is that the WebView is, by default, the android system browser. My audio library and webGL don't work in the system browser, just in chrome. I know there's a way to get a chrome-based WebView in an Android application because they reference it here:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Does anyone know how to get the WebView to be chrome based? Below is my mainActivity.java code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "http://www.cs.stolaf.edu/users/lipson/MusicVisualization/musicVis.html";
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you referenced, the features you want are in WebView v36 which was only available in the L-preview and are available in WebView v37/Chromium M37 as announced on the [Android Developer website announcement for Android 5.0 Lollipop](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html#WebView).

Since you are doing audio, the emulator may not work so you best bet is to test on a device. Set your minimum SDK to API 21 and try your app on a device with Android 5.0.

Comment: But the link says: "Android 4.4 (KitKat) includes a new WebView component based on the Chromium open source project."

Comment: KitKat is stuck at WebView v30 which doesn't have WebGL or WebAudio. Only when the devices are upgraded to Lollipop will they get WebView v37 and up.

Comment: Ah, yes. After reading through it again more thoroughly I understand. I'll try running it on an emulator, thanks!

Comment: how to check WebView version?